# .val() is giving me undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, undefined

I'm trying to get whatever text is written into the input field to be shown in a popup when I hit the enter key, but it always shows up undefined. (The popup says "test blah blah undefined"). I've been staring at this for a few days and searching for solutions, but I can't figure it out!

Is it because I'm selecting the wrong object for keydown? Is there a syntax error that I'm just not catching? Thank you!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test jQuery Thing</title>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $("#document").ready(function() {
  $(document).keydown(function(e){
   //enter key pressed
   if (e.keyCode == 13){
    alert("test blah blah " + $("#testField").val());
   };
  });
 }); // end of ready function
</script>

</head>

<body>
<section class="stuff">
 <input type="text" class="testField">
</section>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is about a typo.

Comment: As the two answer have already fixed your problem..  in CSS / JS `.` are for class selectors, and `#` are for ID selectors. Your original post is trying to reference a field by ID, but the field has that selector as a class.

Comment: I don't see how it's about a typo. Could you explain?

Comment: I was making my way down the page. Gotcha. I thought something wasn't working. Feel like a dummy now. Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 6):

jQuery uses standard css selector so `$("#testField")` looks for an element with an id of "testField". So your input should should be `id="testField"` :

```
<input type="text" id="testField">
```

To search for an element with a "class" of "testField", use this `$(".testField")`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I sure feel like an idiot now. Can't for the life of me realize that I was using the wrong symbol.

Answer (score 1):

Your input has class testField, not id; change `#` to `.`:

```
alert("test blah blah " + $(".testField").val());
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to select your element using an "id" selector, not a "class" selector. The proper way to do that would be:

```
$(".testField").val()
```

Likewise, you could also fix your HTML:

```
<section class="stuff">
    <input type="text" class="test-field" id="testField">
</section>
```